# 2 Sample KS test - something seems wrong

Tags: python, scipy, statistics, kolmogorov-smirnov

I am attempting to run a Kolmogorov-Smirnoff test using the ks_2samp function from scipy to determine if histograms of data are from the same distribution. The returned p-value doesn't seem quite right sometimes though...

For example with this histogram:

[image: Histogram.jpg]

```
aa, bb, cc = ax1.hist(list1, numpy.arange(a-1, b+3, c), alpha = .5, align = 'mid', rwidth=1, linestyle = 'dashed', linewidth = 1.5)

dd, ee, ff = ax1.hist(list2, numpy.arange(a-1, b+3, c), alpha = .5, align = 'mid',rwidth=1)

print ks_2samp(aa, dd)`[1]`
```

I get a p-value returned of about .96, which really don't seem right...am I doing something wrong? Shouldn't these histograms be different enough that the p-value would be lower?

Comment: what you probably want to do is `ks_2samp(list1, list2)`

Comment: Huh interesting, that is exactly what I'm looking for thanks! Now I get a p-value of 1.8e-5, which makes way more sense. I was thinking the function maybe wouldn't have worked that way since I was analysing a histogram...seems non-intuitive to me but maybe I just don't understand how the function actually works haha thanks again

Comment: @cel That should be an (in fact, *the*) answer.

Answer (score 3):

`ks_2samp` applies the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test to two samples and tests the null hypothesis that both come from the same distribution.

Therefore `ks_2samp` also takes the two samples (here `list1` and `list2`) as input.

```
ks_2samp(list1, list2)
```